# When assigning function to object inside another function, what really happens in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Look at this code for example:

```
var arr = [];

var assignFunction = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr[i] = function() {
      console.log(i);
    }

  }
}

arr[0];
arr[1];
arr[2];
```

You would expect it will assign a function that you can call/run, but its not. I'm looking for good explanation what its really doing. `arr[i]` is `typeof` function, meaning it is being assigned, but will never run and print anything to console.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not"? That function is certainly runnable. You just don't run it.

Comment: `arr[0]` is function, just like `assignFunction` is a function. `arr[0]()` will run this function, just like `assignFunction()` will run _that_ function.

Comment: And then he will have problem with closures.It will display 3 by 3 times.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai: yes, that we have :) But it's not very relevant. Probably will be their next question (which will be dup-closed within a minute)

Comment: Also title says object, you use an array

Comment: `arr[0]` is an object of type `Function`. You can call it the same way you call any function: `arr[0]()`.

Answer (score 0):

## The "Problem"

You need to call `assignFunction` to assign the functions to the indices off `arr`. After that you can execute a function with `arr[index]()`.

why each function prints `3` in the console, you can read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example/750506#750506)

## Working Example

```js
var arr = []

var assignFunction = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr[i] = function() {
      console.log(i)
    }
  }
}

assignFunction()

arr[0]()
arr[1]()
arr[2]()
```